# Need a "SOAP Client with WSSE authentication" ... does Visual Studio fit this need?

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008, authentication

The Web Service I need to connect to has the requirement above.    I can consume this web service in VS 2008 but cannot use it because I don't know how to authenticate.  I need to specify credentails, however there is no "header" method exposed.  I have tried something like the following:

```
UltraDNSWebReference.UltraWebServiceService clientProxy = 
    new UltraDNSWebReference.UltraWebServiceService();

clientProxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
    "MyUserName", "MYPassword");
```

but I still get an authentication error.  I CAN connect successfully using the SOAPUI testing platform, so I know it is not incorrect credentials or blocked IP.

This WebService API states:

> The Neustar Ultra Services API
>   authenticates a user and requests with
>   a WSSE UserName token in a SOAP
>   header.

Is it possible for me to use this webservice within Visual Studio???

I have tried Add Service Reference.  I can successfully consume the WSDL and create an object but have no idea how to provide the authentication.  For instance I have tried the following:

```
//Create client object  
  ServiceReference1.UltraDNSClient client = new ServiceReference1.UltraDNSClient();
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUserName";
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword";
```

So, above I have my client object, and this object has all access to all the methods in the API.  However, I can NOT use any methods because I have not authenticated correctly.  The API does not provide any sort of "header()" type method.  For instance, for another webservice I use (and yes, this used Add Web Reference but the concept stays the same):

```
//Use the Web Reference to create the header object
StockLogoWebService.Header headerObject = new StockLogoWebService.Header();

//Assign the username (Username is all Xignite requires for authentication)
headerObject.Username = "janedoe@yahoo.com";

//Assign this header to the proxy object
xLogogsTest.HeaderValue = headerObject;

//Use any exposed methods
xLogosTest.anyMethod()
```

Above I have used the header() method to specify my credentials.  If a WSDL does not provide a header method, and just states the credentials must be supplied in the SOAP header, how does one accomplish this in Visual Studio?

The WSDL can be found at:

http://ultra-api.ultradns.com:8008/UltraDNS_WS?wsdl

Comment: If they mean "WS-Security", then yes. Try just using "Add Service Reference".

Comment: John,  Thank you.  I appreciate the confirmation that VS supports their service.  However I am still unclear on how to authenticate and would appreciate your assistance.  How do i get an "WSSE Username token in a SOAP Header" using visual studio?

Comment: I told you. Use "Add Service Reference". Have you tried that yet?

Comment: You can now edit your question.  Indent code with four spaces.

Comment: I have received the following response from UltraDNS support: "Thank you for contacting UltraDNS (www.ultradns.com).  All UltraDNS customers must request permissions to access the the SOAP API by providing all IP addresses that will need access."

Comment: As a result, I will be unable to assist you further.

Comment: Johon, I can provide the WSDL in file form if there is a place on this forum to upload it (I can't seem to post it).  The company in question also just sent me some sample java code  that utilizes the HandlerResolver.java class in the javax.xml.ws.handler package to set the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can add WSSE security headers to your service endpoint in the web / app config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
          <! -- your binding details -->
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint <your endpoint details>>
        <headers>
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
              <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"></wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```